# If your basis is not orthogonal, does this formula for subspace projection still work?

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Proposition 3.3.** Let $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_r$ be an orthogonal basis in $E$. Then the orthogonal projection $P_E\mathbf{v}$ of a vector $\mathbf{v}$ is given by the formula
> $$P_E\mathbf{v}=\sum_{k=1}^r\alpha_k\mathbf{v}_k,\qquad\text{where}\qquad\alpha_k=\frac{(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v}_k)}{\|\mathbf{v}_k\|^2}.$$
> In other words
> $$P_E\mathbf{v}=\sum_{k=1}^r\frac{(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{v}_k)}{\|\mathbf{v}_k\|^2}\mathbf{v}_k.\tag{3.1}$$

Formula 3.1 is the formula for projection a vector $\mathbf{v}$ onto a subspace $E$ spanned by a set of orthogonal basis. I was wondering whether we need the basis $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_r$  to be orthogonal for this formula to work. If the basis is not orthogonal, where is the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary.  Make up an example and see what happens.  Then go back to the derivation of the projection formula and find where orthogonality was used.

Comment: If the $v_i$ are are non-orthonormal, you have construct the orthogonal projector as $P_E = V(V^TV)^{-1}V^T$ where $V = [v_1, \ldots, v_r]$ see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra))